# How and where to add crossdomain.xml in neo4j so that its available on localhost:7474/crossdomain.xml?

Tags: unity-game-engine, neo4j, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

I am sending a Basic Auth Post request to neo4j REST

`x.x.x.85:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`

I am using unity www at `x.x.x.15` which requires crossdomain.xml to be present at  `x.x.x.85:7474/crossdomain.xml`. Where and how should I get crossdomain.xml at the desired location?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can't add arbitrary resources to be served by Neo4j.

You could put it behind a HTTP server with reverse proxy capabilities (Apache HTTP Server, nginx) to serve the file and proxy the rest of the requests to Neo4j.

However, the real question is whether you should be exposing your database directly, to be used by a client browser (which is the reason why you need a crossdomain file) which could send any query, including `MATCH(n) DETACH DELETE n`, a.k.a. the new `DROP TABLE` (or `DROP DATABASE`).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was using it in unity desktop app and then was facing issue in unity web app and you are right that database should not be exposed directly.